# Options for getting from Kayseri (Turkey) to Goreme

Tags: airport-transfer, turkey, cappadocia

We're traveling to Istanbul and then Kayseri to visit Goreme in November (4th). I'd like to know, other than car rental, what other options are available for us to get to Goreme/Urgup. How do we buy tickets (bus/train) from Kayseri to Goreme online? Is there a website where we can check time table/schedule to be able to have a clear plan for our trip?

Comment: That was a lot of questions at once, some opinion based and some quite vague and unclear. Only you can know if it is worth to spend a night in Kayseri. If you want to go by public transport, you have to be more precise where you are going. Looking for a bus from Kayseri to the Cappadocia region does not make sense, since Kayseri *is* in Cappadocia.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo, You're right. I edited my question to remove the vague part and tried to made it clearer as to what do I need to know. I did search and found related questions but couldn't find information about buses online. What I mostly read is beware of taxi drivers for they often charge way more than what the real price is and hotels sometimes offer free shuttle from Kayseri airport to their resident. To be clear, I know what not to do, but I don't know what to do.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo The question seems very clear to me after OP's edit, I think [it should be reopened](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4837/is-this-question-still-unclear).

Answer (score 2):

> I'd like to know, other than car rental, what other options are
>   available for us to get to Goreme/Urgup.

No train is available, but I see two bus companies serving between Kayseri and Göreme.

- [Kamil Koç](https://www.kamilkoc.com.tr/)
- [Metro](https://www.metroturizm.com.tr/en/)

> How do we buy tickets (bus/train) from Kayseri to Goreme online?

It is possible to buy tickets online. Both companies accept Visa, Mastercard and American Express. When available, you can also select *Kayseri-Otogar* and *Göreme-Otogar* as departure and arrival stops. *Otogar* means bus terminal.

> Is there a website where we can check time table/schedule to be able
>   to have a clear plan for our trip?

The company websites include the timetables. There are 7-8 expeditions (for each way) on the date you have mentioned.

In addition, a transfer from Kayseri Erkilet Airport (ASR) to the bus terminal is possible via [Havaş](http://www.havas.net/tr/Hizmetlerimiz/OtobusHizmetleriVeOtopark/OtobusServisNoktalari/Pages/Kayseri.aspx). The transfer fee is paid on the bus, no ticket is required in advance. Google Maps and Yandex Maps don't show any public transport option.